# DIY Home automation problem

Tags: arduino

this may not be new but I wasn't successful to find a safe and holistic solution yet.

I'm planning to automat all light fixtures, Shutters and exhaust fans. Ready made Shelly's, Sonoff 's and the like are mind blowing expensive.

Since it's a new home, I got a qualified electrician to wire all loads to a central control box, also all 68 wall switches are routed back to the same control box. i.e Star topolgy. This is 4x the conventional buss topolgy wiring cost,however it is much much cheaper than current professional market offerings.

All wires are rated for 220VAC and according to load requirements.

Passes to load fixtures are totally separated from passes to wall switches to prevent interference after moving into automation.

All 220vac circuits are protected by appropriate MCBs in a dedicated distribution box located next to the control box.

Under the current system configuration:
1- The distribution box feeds 220vac to the control box
2- The control box contains 2 terminal blocks, A and B.

Terminal block B receives 220vac from the distribution box and deliver it to standard 220vac wall switches.

Terminal block A receives 220vac from wall switches and deliver it to the corresponding load.

To achieve home automation, I intend to, within the premises of the control box:

1- Implement relay modules such that, connect the 220vac power source coming from the distribution box (electricity) to the relay's comm. port. And connect the load (Lamp) to the relay's NO.

2- Feed 5vdc to the wall switches from an independent power supply (SMPS), and scan them by an MCU (Arduino, RPi, ...etc), and control the relay's coils correspondingly.

I will use famous blue Chinese relay modules selling on Amazon as industrial relays price's tripled the past 8 months.

As far as I understand:

1- Switching 220VAC rated standard wall switches using 5VDC and only mAmps, should pose no stress on the switch. Correct me if I'm wrong.

2- Also, there will not be voltage drop issue for the same reason, although the average wire length per switch is about 20 meters back and forth.

If so, how to implement the ready made 8 relay modules safely, in this real life situation?

I'm trying to balance cost/functionality without compromising on safety.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, welcome to the site. Unfortunately your question is problematic for multiple reasons: 1) It's extremely broad (too many questions in one); you should narrow it to a specific item. 2) Asking for opinions is off-topic; answers are meant to be definitive and objective as much as possible. Solutions would be varied and based on opinion as there's no single correct method.

Comment: Hi @JYelton, as for 1) I felt telling the whole story is better than just asking one question, to escape the XY-problem, As for 2) By critical opinion I meant an expert judgement to point out any problem and also propose a valid safe solution. However, if you still find this violates forum rules, please notify me so I shall edit it.

Comment: Not so much a violation as a best practice. If you can condense it to ask a single question, you will be better received. You can always ask multiple questions as separate posts and refer them to each other as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your pinch point is actually your local laws, standards and insurance

Have you talked with your insurance company? Local permit issuer and inspecting authority?  I think you are going to have serious entitlement/coverage issues with brewing your own AC mains controls using cheap Chinese.

I think you missed an opportunity (or maybe did not miss it yet) to use **low voltage lighting and controls**, for which the safety codes are *much relaxed*. If you were doing this stuff at 24 volts, that is a happy medium between keeping voltage low and not getting mauled by voltage drop on the lighting circuits.

24 volt lighting kit is readily available from a wide variety of sources.

### Voltage drop and switch stress

Both of these are proportional to current.  It is covered by Ohm's Law.

The usual problem with lowering voltage is the current increases in proportion. So going to 24V lighting would 10x your current, but that should still be viable for most 1000-2000 lumen lighting loads assuming they used regulation-sized AC mains cable such as 1.0mm<sup>2</sup> or 14 AWG.

As far as the switch control lines, the voltage drop is decided by the current. My impression is your current on the switch lines will be  *micro-amps* of sense current.  No problem there.

The problem with AC rated switches on DC is AC switches rely on the AC current reversal every 10ms to snuff out the arc from interrupting current flow.  They are not well-equipped to snuff a DC arc (which requires special stuff).  As such, when AC switches have a DC voltage rating, it is typically 1/10 that of the AC voltage rating at same current.  However 5 volts is rather docile stuff, and in any case your current will be micro-amps.

> 3- An RC snubber circuit is needed between the relay and the load to deal with the bacK EMF.

No, use relays **within their rating**. There shouldn't be any back EMF on basically resistive lighting circuits, unless you are driving HID or ancient fluorescent ballasts.

> I'm trying to balance cost/functionality without compromising on safety.

Using cheap Chinese with AC mains is the definition of compromising on safety.  The best way to recover (and stay cheap) is to use a certified 24 volt power supply then run the whole show on low voltage.

Comment: Hi @Harper, I think you are saying that if I'm only using 5vdc for control signals that will be both ok for the AC switch stress and no voltage drop problem. Also, RC snubber is not needed in your context. If so that's fine and very helpful.

Comment: @Ahmed yes, milliamps of 5VDC for signal purposes won't have a voltage drop or switch burn-up issue.

Comment: Hi again @Harper, is there a way to stress test the 8 relay module (blue ice cube 10A 250v) like the ones selling on Amazon to verify there quality?

Comment: @AhmedRamzy you don't need to stress test it. Nationally Recognized Testing Labs such as UL have already done that for you, simply select a relay with a UL listing (for equipment) or UR (UL recognition for components), or equivalent mark of another NRTL.  CE, CCC, FCC and ROHS are not NRTLs.